# How to reset value of ASP.NET ObjectdataSource parameter

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding, objectdatasource

I have a gridview that is bound to an objectdatasource. There is paging and it works fine. Now there is also a searchbox on the page, and if someone clicks on the search button I want to reset the startRow parameter to 0, but it doesn't work: the current page is passed to the Select method of the datasource.

```
       <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCars" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        DataKeyNames="Id"            
        AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
        PageSize="2" DataSourceID="dataSource"           
        OnDataBound="GridView_DataBound" OnRowCommand="gvCars_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvCars_RowDataBound">               

       <Columns>
        ... 
       </Columns>             

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dataSource" EnablePaging="true" runat="server" 
        SelectCountMethod="GetCount" 
        MaximumRowsParameterName="PageSize" 
        StartRowIndexParameterName="StartRow" SortParameterName="SortExpression"
        SelectMethod="Get" 
        TypeName="DataSource">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="startRow" />  
            <asp:Parameter Name="pageSize" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="sortExpression" />                  
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="searchTerm" ControlID="txtSearchTerm" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

and in the codebehind I try to do:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataSource.SelectParameters["startRow"].DefaultValue = "0";
        gvCars.DataBind();
    }
```

but the get method of the objectdatasource is called with whatever page user was at the moment that he clicked the searchbutton.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the `StartRowIndex` parameter in the `OnSelecting` event of `ObjectDataSource`.

Also, since you require that, when SearchButton is clicked, objectDataSource should start with row 0, so you need to identify which control caused the postback, and if that is your search button, reset the `StartRowIndex` parameter.

Below 3 steps should be performed:

1.) Identify if search button was clicked

a.) I will recommend to see [**`this blog`**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-find-the-control-that-caused-PostBack-in-ASP.Net.aspx) as to how to get the control especially a button, that caused postback.

Basically idea is to use a `HiddenField` and set this hiddenField value to our Search button control name, whenever search button is clicked.

We then use a global variable named say `controlName` to set the value from hidden field in Page_Load event.

2.) Handle the `OnSelecting` event of `ObjectDataSource`.

3.) define an `OnClientClick` event for your Search button. Why this event is used is because, when search button is clicked, we will set the HiddenField value to ID of our SearchButton.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dataSource"
     OnSelecting="dataSource_Selecting" ... />
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server"
      OnClick="btnSearch_Click"  
      OnClientClick = "SetSource(this.id)"/>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hidSourceID" runat="server" />
```

Also, include the below script in `<head>` tag of your `.aspx` markup

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function SetSource(SourceID) {
        var hidSourceID =
        document.getElementById("<%=hidSourceID.ClientID%>");
        hidSourceID.value = SourceID;
    }
</script>
```

Code behind::

```
public partial class Default: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string controlName = string.Empty;

     // Page Load event
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Form[hidSourceID.UniqueID] != null &&    
                Request.Form[hidSourceID.UniqueID] != string.Empty)
                 {
                    controlName = Request.Form[hidSourceID.UniqueID];
                 }
         }

  // OnSelecting event of ObjectDataSource
      protected void dataSource_Selecting(object sender, 
                                          ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
     {
        // here controlName is a variable set in Page_Load event
         if (controlName != null)
         {
             // check if your search button was clicked
             if (controlName.Equals("btnSearch"))
             {
                 // reset the startRowIndex to zero
                 // note that e.Arguments will work
                 // e.InputParameters will not work
                 e.Arguments.StartRowIndex = 0;                 
             }
         }
     }
}
```

That's all to resetting the  start row value of ObjectDataSource, when your search button is clicked.